# How to enable row value editable in datagridview of win app?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I set the data source programmatically to datagridview of the windows application.

I set the "Enable editing" to true & readonly property is also set to false.

so is there any thing I'm missing?

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the [four conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx):

1. The underlying data source supports editing.
2. The `DataGridView` control is enabled.
3. The `EditMode` property value is not `EditProgrammatically`.
4. The `ReadOnly` properties of the cell, row, column, and control are all set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

if the Readonly  properties of the cell, row , column are all set to false but the editting mode is not enable yet, then check the ImeMode properties and set it to "ON".